# highcharts x-axis for 1 year displays tick/label of year +1

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts column chart with an x-axis for an entire year. Its type is `datetime` and its `min`/`max` is from 2014-01-01 to 2014-12-31.

Why is the tick/label for Jan **2015** displayed?

Full source at http://jsfiddle.net/nkjm2691/1/

I tried a number of things like setting the end date to `Date.UTC(2014, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59)` and experimenting with `tickInterval`. What I need eventually is a monthly tick (i.e. irregular interval) and the labels centered between the ticks. Using some voodoo logic to calculate the offset only ever works if the chart has a fixed width.

Quite surprisingly doing more or less the same with a chart of type `areaspline` works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fm86v8fe/

I also checked a number of related SO questions like [Is there a reliable way to have a 1 month auto generated tick interval with high charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15061574/131929) and [HighCharts xAxis - tickInterval for month](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20795975/131929) but they don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkjm2691/1/). Just changing from `type: 'column'` to `type: 'line'` removes he label. Why?

That is because any chart type that is "column like" has a `pointRange`. This is defined differently depending on context, but for your `datetime` x-axis it is ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange)):

> On linear and datetime axes, the range will be computed as the distance between the two closest data points.

It is this `pointRange` that causes your column to have their specific width. They have a span across the x-axis. As you can see on your chart each column has a range of a week, not just a single millisecond (which is the case for line-charts, and similar).

From my understanding this causes Highcharts to take some extra space to somehow better suit the point range of the chart points.

There are several things you can do. You can manually override the `pointRange` like this:

```
series: { pointRange: 1, data: ... }
```

This will make each column only 1 millisecond thick, and removes the label. You can fix the width with `pointWidth`:

```
series: { pointRange: 1, pointWidth: 10, data: ... }
```

Note however that this is static, so if columns suddenly get too close they'll start overlapping. [Here's a JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/nkjm2691/3/).

Also you could do nothing and just set the `max` to be far enough back in time for `pointRange` not to include too much extra space, like this:

```
xAxis: { min : Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1), max : Date.UTC(2014, 11, 28) }
```

Note here that Highcharts seems to add more space once you go over to the 29th of December. Unfortunately I'm not exactly sure how this spacing is chosen (the 29th is a Monday..?).

Sebastian suggested some solutions that don't involve this type of manipulation at all. The chosen "solution" depends on the other requirements and desired behavior of the chart.

Comment: What worked best for me was to use `pointRange: 1` and a dynamic value for `pointWidth`.

Answer (score 1):

Set a max date as 1.12, remove time and set `maxPadding` as 0 value. In case when you use a tiem (23:59:59) tick Interval cannot be calculated properly. Second solution is using [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner)

https://jsfiddle.net/nkjm2691/50/

Comment: "Set a max date as 1.12" - uuhhm no, that violates the requirement of displaying an entire year. I need 12 months not just 11. If I modify your fiddle to use max date 31.12 it shows the same problem. Also, do you have any idea why my area spline example doesn't suffer from this?